# Drools: Sliding Window : Time Based : Retract after a given time

Tags: java, time, drools

Folks,

I am new to drools. Please help me out with a scenario.

**Scenario:**

1. Out of many events entered in last 20sec, compare specific facts and take the action.
2. Facts older than 20sec should keep getting retracted.

**Code Tried:**

```
rule "First Rule"
    when
        Alarm(getCustField("Id") != currentAlarm.getCustField("Id")) over window:time(20s) 
    then
        ............
        ............
```

Tried putting some log statement in when part and could see comparison happening with all the facts in working memory and not just with entered in last 20s ones. After tring the same after an hour, could see facts in working memory as it is.

What is exact behavior of "over window:time(20s)"?

Answer (score 0):

A sliding time window selects a subset of events in Working Memory, not surprisingly those that are not older than the duration specified in the `window:time` phrase.

To get rid of events older than some time, set an *explicit expiration offset* using e.g. `@expires(20s)` in a DRL `declare` statement or use the implicit expiration strategy which, however, only works in STREAM mode and relies on the set of *all* rules. (The latter may very easily result in events never being retracted.)

Comment: when
        Alarm( PRINT_SOME_LOG(), getCustField("Id") != currentAlarm.getCustField("Id")) over window:time(20s) 
    then ||||||    


I printed some log, as mentioned in snippet above. Could see when part evaluating all data present in the memory and not just last 20s. 

Any idea? Why this strange behavior?

Comment: How would I know? I don't see your code, I don't see your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timer` to remove events that are older than 20s:

```
rule "Remove old Events"
timer (20s)
when
    $a: Alarm()
then
    retract ($a)
end
```

And use your rule to collect only events that are not yet 20s old:

```
rule "First Rule"
when
    Alarm(...) over window:time(20s) 
then
    ...
end
```

**Timer** will make sure your rule only triggers if the condition is held for the time specified on timer.

**over-window** allows you to pick up events that are on a window [specified time into the past, now]